# Python dictionary data manipulation

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dataset in Python:

> data = [{'id': '431876400186007/insights/page_fans_country/lifetime', 'name': 'page_fans_country', 'description': 'Lifetime: Aggregated Facebook location data, sorted by country, about the people who like your Page. (Unique Users)', 'title': 'Lifetime Likes by Country', 'period': 'lifetime', 'values': [{'end_time': '2016-07-02T07:00:00+0000', 'value': {'PK': 100, 'AT': 151, 'SK': 81, 'RO': 488, 'BE': 367, 'ID': 91, 'MX': 82, 'GB': 2063, 'CY': 1820, 'TN': 92, 'NL': 418, 'ES': 230, 'RU': 99, 'CZ': 188, 'AR': 105, 'BD': 80, 'PH': 144, 'AU': 550, 'GE': 178, 'GR': 273321, 'CO': 98, 'DZ': 86, 'US': 2447, 'BG': 732, 'MA': 95, 'MK': 831, 'PT': 160, 'CH': 187, 'CA': 317, 'DE': 4463, 'AL': 1588, 'FR': 388, 'PE': 204, 'AE': 142, 'TR': 547, 'BR': 609, 'SE': 495, 'HU': 120, 'IT': 845, 'PL': 186, 'IN': 114, 'EG': 217, 'NO': 97, 'DK': 77, 'RS': 444}}, {'end_time': '2016-07-03T07:00:00+0000', 'value': {'PK': 100, 'AT': 151, 'SK': 81, 'RO': 488, 'BE': 367, 'ID': 91, 'MX': 82, 'GB': 2063, 'CY': 1820, 'TN': 92, 'NL': 418, 'ES': 230, 'RU': 99, 'CZ': 188, 'AR': 105, 'BD': 80, 'PH': 144, 'AU': 548, 'GE': 178, 'GR': 273275, 'CO': 98, 'DZ': 86, 'US': 2447, 'BG': 732, 'MA': 95, 'MK': 831, 'PT': 159, 'CH': 187, 'CA': 317, 'DE': 4462, 'AL': 1588, 'FR': 388, 'PE': 204, 'AE': 142, 'TR': 547, 'BR': 607, 'SE': 495, 'HU': 120, 'IT': 845, 'PL': 186, 'IN': 114, 'EG': 217, 'NO': 97, 'DK': 77, 'RS': 445}}, {'end_time': '2016-07-04T07:00:00+0000', 'value': {'PK': 100, 'AT': 151, 'SK': 81, 'RO': 488, 'BE': 367, 'ID': 90, 'MX': 82, 'GB': 2063, 'CY': 1820, 'TN': 92, 'NL': 418, 'ES': 230, 'RU': 99, 'CZ': 188, 'AR': 105, 'BD': 80, 'PH': 144, 'AU': 547, 'GE': 178, 'GR': 273249, 'CO': 98, 'DZ': 86, 'US': 2445, 'BG': 732, 'MA': 95, 'MK': 831, 'PT': 159, 'CH': 187, 'CA': 317, 'DE': 4460, 'AL': 1588, 'FR': 388, 'PE': 204, 'AE': 142, 'TR': 547, 'BR': 608, 'SE': 495, 'HU': 120, 'IT': 845, 'PL': 186, 'IN': 114, 'EG': 217, 'NO': 97, 'DK': 77, 'RS': 444}}]}]

I want to make a dictionary with country data like this:

```
{'PK': 100, 
 'AT': 151, 
 'SK': 81, 
 'RO': 488, 
 'BE': 367, 
 'ID': 91, 
 'MX': 82, 
 'GB': 2063, 
 'CY': 1820, 
 'TN': 92, 
 'NL': 418, 
 'ES': 230, 
 'RU': 99, 
 'CZ': 188, 
 'AR': 105, 
 'BD': 80, 
 'PH': 144, 
 'AU': 550, 
 'GE': 178, 
 'GR': 273321, 
 'CO': 98}
```

What  should I do?

I cannot use the following code:

```
data['value']
```

as I could in an ordinary dictionary.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have already tried, add your code. As it stands, this question seems more like a request for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print data[0]['values'][0]['value']` seems to work. It prints out this:

```
{'BD': 80, 'BE': 367, 'FR': 388, 'BG': 732, 'BR': 609, 'RU': 99, 'NL': 418, 'NO': 97, 'RO': 488, 'CH': 187, 'CO': 98, 'GR': 273321, 'CA': 317, 'CZ': 188, 'CY': 1820, 'GB': 2063, 'SK': 81, 'SE': 495, 'DK': 77, 'DE': 4463, 'HU': 120, 'DZ': 86, 'MK': 831, 'PT': 160, 'TR': 547, 'TN': 92, 'PE': 204, 'PK': 100, 'PH': 144, 'PL': 186, 'AE': 142, 'EG': 217, 'AL': 1588, 'IT': 845, 'AR': 105, 'AU': 550, 'AT': 151, 'IN': 114, 'ID': 91, 'ES': 230, 'MA': 95, 'RS': 444, 'GE': 178, 'US': 2447, 'MX': 82}
```

In your `data` array, it is the first item, and in that item is a key `values` whose first element has a key `value`.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, it looks like the `values` array is an aggregate snapshot, not a period value. Meaning that you should be able to just pull the last value and use that:

```
countryData = data[0]['values'][-1]['value']
```

`[0]` pulls the first (and only) item of the outer list.

`['values']` pulls the list of snapshots from the dictionary.

`[-1]` gets the last snapshot.

`['value']` gets the country data from that snapshot.